# highcharts-vue gives error about the highcharts HTML element

Tags: javascript, vue.js, highcharts, vuejs2, vue-component

I am using vue and the [Highcharts-Vue](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-vue) plugin, to insert Highcharts charts in my project.

Following the instructions [here](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-vue), I first install it and then I register it globally. I go to my `main.js` and add it like so

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import HighchartsVue from 'highcharts-vue'

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  vuetify, 
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')

Vue.use(HighchartsVue)
```

Then in my component (`Hello.vue` file) ,

```
<template>
  <div> 
    <highcharts :options="chartOptions"></highcharts>
  </div>
</template>

<script> 
    import { mapGetters, mapActions } from 'vuex';  
    export default {
        name:'Hello',        
        data(){
          return{   
            chartOptions: {
                series: [{
                data: [1,2,3] 
              }]
            }
          }
        }
    }
</script>
```

The problem is that when I go to my app, I can see the chart , but in the browser console I get

`[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <highcharts> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.`

Any help? How can I debug this? I am a Vue beginner, and I follow the instructions given, so its hard for me to get what is wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Check this online example: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-6mk6q?fontsize=14. If it doesn't help you, could you reproduce your issue in this template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move this line:

```js
Vue.use(HighchartsVue)
```

Before the `new Vue(...)`. Currently you're registering it after Vue has rendered the page.